# Payment Problem!

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, payment-gateway, multicurrency

We have a website containing 3 different stores, Norwegian , Swedish , English

The default store is the Norwegian , and we have different currency for each store , NOK , SEK , US Dollar.

When customer bought from Norwegian store , every thing is work.
but when he bought from Swedish or English store , he placed the order and received the order confirmation , but we can not process the order because it shows with status : **Suspected Fraud**.
[image]
and we are unable to invoice or ship.
when we check our bank account , we found that we received the payment as normal.

Any one has solution for this please ????

Comment: Which payment service are you using? Is the suspected fraud status being sent from the payment provider (such as PayPal's IPN)?

Answer (score 0):

Does the currency exchange rate for the other countries work out correctly? If it is mismatching the actual cost, the payment provider may find it looks fraudulent. This may help - [Persistent suspected fraud orders via Paypal when checking out with non-base currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113122/persistent-suspected-fraud-orders-via-paypal-when-checking-out-with-non-base-cur).